# Using python to determine if two strings are opposites given conditions

Tags: python, function

If we had certain conditions to fulfill such as

```
a is the opposite of b
c is the opposite of h
l is the opposite of r
```

the opposite of the string `acl` would be `bhr`
Do you guys think you can help me figure out how I would go about building a function that when given two strings will return a boolean that lets me know whether the given strings are opposite. for example input: `opposite("ahl","bcr")` would return `True` while `("ahl","bbr")` would return `False`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the rule that a string should be opposite of another string?

Comment: the rules are a is the opposite of b
c is the opposite of h
l is the opposite of r

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like a string compare, except that for every character, there would be a lookup table to get a translated value like so:

```
lookup = {
    'a': 'b',
    'c': 'h',
    'l': 'r'
}


def opposite(one, two):
    count = 0
    if len(one) != len(two):
        return False
    for i in one:
        if (lookup[i] != two[count] ):
            return False
        count += 1
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print opposite('acl', 'bhr')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the lookup table, then this is a one-liner.

```
lookup = {
    'a': 'b',
    'c': 'h',
    'l': 'r'
}


def opposite(str1, str2):
    return [ lookup[c] for c in str1] == [ c for c in str2 ]
```

Depending on the actual situation (whether you know the first string contains only "acl" and the second only their opposites), you may need to have bidirectional lookup:

```
lookup = {
    'a': 'b',
    'c': 'h',
    'l': 'r',
    'b': 'a',
    'h': 'c',
    'r': 'l'
}
```

And if you want to have an exception raised when there are invalid characters in the input, you may change the function:

```
def opposite(str1, str2):
    return [ lookup[c] for c in str1] == [ lookup[lookup[c]] for c in str2 ]
```

Comment: What do you think I could do if I wanted my function to also return the boolean true if the second string was an opposite of the first but using the reverse of the first? so both opposite("ahl","bcr") and opposite("ahl","rcb") would be true. I am guessing using the reverse string function but not sure

Comment: If you have the full lookup (the one with six entries), the function works both ways. If you look at the lower function, it compares opposite of str1 to opposite of opposite (i.e. the original but with validity check) of str2. That way you may reverse the arguments. (If this is your homework, do not submit it before really understanding how it works.)